# How to fold into a multi level map using gpars and map reduce

Tags: groovy, gpars

I have a collection of maps that looks something like this:

```
def list = [
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 3, value: 1.01],
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 4, value: 1.02],
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 4, value: 1.03],
    [key1: 'DEF', key2: 3, value: 1.04]]
```

I'm trying to get a result that looks like this that groups and sums up the values for the unique key1 and key2 values and results in a hierarchy.

```
['ABC':[[key2: 2, value: 1.01]
        [key2: 4, value: 2.05]],   //note values are added
 'DEF':[[key2: 3, value: 1.04]]
]
```

There are many examples of mapping routines that have one key, but what is the best way to fold these when using more than one key?

One solution I thought of was to use groupby to get the list grouped by the first key.  The problem there is the combine or reduce must then be run on the sub list of each element:

```
list.parallel
.map{it}
.groupBy{it.key1}
```

at this point I want to reduce on the .value() of the grouped maps which I can't really do within the chain

I also tried to use combine, which works a bit like the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296325/group-and-sum-collection-in-groovy?lq=1).  However it looks like if combine gets a map back, it wants to combine it further.

```
def result = list.parallel
        .map{[it.key1, it]}
        .combine({-> [:]})  { map, v -> println "$map - $v = ${v.getClass()}"
            map[v.key2] = map[v.key2]?:0 + v.value
            map
        }
```

Then there is the option to just reduce on the maps, but the reduce routine then becomes a pretty complicated beast of combining nested maps.  So I'm wondering if there is something simpler, or should I just run a reduce routine to combine the complex maps.

```
list.parallel
.map{[(it.key1):it]}
.reduce([:]) { a, b ->
   complexMapCombiner(a, b)
}
```

Comment: I was looking at some methods described here for the combining of two maps for the 'complexMapCombiner' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129837/add-two-maps-in-groovy

Comment: Here's one that does the same in a non-parallel fashion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296325/group-and-sum-collection-in-groovy

Answer (score 2):

So here's a solution that works, but is less elegant than I'd like.  If anyone has something better please post an answer.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.gpars', module='gpars', version='1.0.0')

import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.*

def list = [
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 3, value: 1.01],
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 4, value: 1.02],
    [key1: 'ABC', key2: 4, value: 1.03],
    [key1: 'DEF', key2: 3, value: 1.04]]

withPool {
    def mapInner = { entrylist ->
         withPool{
             entrylist.getParallel()
                 .map{[it.key2, it.value]}
                 .combine(0) {acc, v -> acc + v}.getParallel()
                 .map{[key2: it.key, value: it.value]}.collection
         }
    }

    //for dealing with bug when only 1 list item
    def collectSingle = { entrylist ->
        def first = entrylist[0]
        return [[key2:(first.key2), value:first.value]]
    }

    def result = list.parallel
        .groupBy{it.key1}.getParallel()
        .map{ [(it.key) : (it.value?.size())>1?mapInner.call(it.value):collectSingle.call(it.value) ] }
        .reduce([:]) {a, b -> a + b}


    println "result = $result"
}
```